# WCF REST operation object null reference on first call

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have written a sample REST based WCF service with the following URI template contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/entity/{entityIdString}/mem",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Task<Entity> TestEntityJsonMemory(string entityIdString);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/entity/{entityIdString}/string",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Task<System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message> TestEntityJsonString(string entityIdString);
```

First is to return the entity object direct to WCF to serialise (with DataContractJsonSerializer) which the other is meant to perform custom JSON.NET serialisation before passing on as a raw Message for performance comparison.

```
public async Task<Entity> TestEntityJsonMemory(string entityIdString)
{
    return await new Tests.TestLoader().TestEntityJsonMemory(entityIdString);
}

public async Task<Message> TestEntityJsonString(string entityIdString)
{
    var entity = await new Tests.TestLoader().TestEntityJsonMemory(entityIdString);
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);

    return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(jsonString, "application/json; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Both operations use the same internal process of loading and caching the test object in memory before returning to the client. The URI that uses standard WCF practice /entity/entityId/mem works fine.

However for /entity/entityId/string it will always throw an exception on the first call before working on subsequent calls.

> Request Error The server encountered an error processing the request.
>   The exception message is 'Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack
>   trace is:
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.TaskMethodInvoker.InvokeEnd(Object
>   instance, Object[]& outputs, IAsyncResult result) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeEnd(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage7(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

There is no event log to inform where this object reference is failing. I cannot tell why the second operation gets into that kind of condition only on first call?

UPDATE 21 Apr 2014

On further digging it appears that on first request, WebOperationContext.Current is null. Why would that be null? And other subsequent requests are fine thereafter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no apparent solution to how WCF loses its request context after the await, the workaround I found was to safe a reference to WebOperationContext.Current prior to awaiting an async method.

After the await, the reference to the original context is thus preserved and usable.

```
// Custom UTF-8 encoding
private static UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);

public async Task<Message> RawMessageOperation(string params)
{
    var webContext = WebOperationContext.Current;
    var result = await whateverAsyncWork(params);

    // Further more use custom utf8 encoding otherwise WCF returns additional encoding characters not parsable as JSON.
    return webContext.CreateTextResponse(JsonConvert.Serialize(result), "application/json; charset=utf-8", utf8);
}
```